# Error :hd1,gpt2 not found

Tags: windows, grub2, dual-boot, grub

i hv windows 8.1 and linux both in my computer.but when i tried to get into windows it wasn't showing me anything after a long wait ,also in Linux i got some errors related to grub.so i uninstalled it and then reinstalled.and added these lines in 40_custom.

```
menuentry "Windows 8" {
    set root='(hd1,gpt2)'
    chainloader /EFI/microsoft/BOOT/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

then by running this "grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" i got output:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...                                                                                                                                  
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.                                                               
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-21-generic                                                                                                                       
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-21-generic                                                                                                                   
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration                                                                                                                   
done
```

but when i reboot,there is an option for windows but when i try to get into that i got error

```
error hd1,gpt2 not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your root to gpt1 or `set root='(hd1,gpt1)'`. The EFI application bootmgfw.efi actually exists in the EFI system partition not the Windows partition.